# How many $n$-digit sequences of $0,1 \ \text{or} \ 2$s contain an odd numbers of $0$s?

Tags: combinatorics

Problem : There are $3^n$ n-digit sequences in which each digit is $0$, $1$ or $2$. How many of these sequences have an odd number of $0$'s ?

Let $o(n)$ = the number of n-digit sequences which have an odd number of $0$'s and
$e(n)$ = the number of n-digit sequences which have an even number of $0$'s.

Obviously $o(n) + e(n) = 3^n$ and by examples I can see that $o(n)=e(n)-1$ but I don't know how to show this.
Moreover if we have $x$ digits to choose from then by examples I see that $o(n) = e(n) - {n}^{x-2}$. And if we consider the number of sequences which have a number congruent to $0$, $1$ respectively $2$ (modulo $3$) of $0$s we see that these numbers are in arithmetic progression.

Can someone prove these assumptions to me or disprove them if they are not right?

Comment: $o(n)=2o(n-1)+e(n-1)=2o(n-1)+3^{n-1}-o(n-1)=3^{n-1}+o(n-1)$?

Comment: o(n) = ${3}^{n-1}$ + o(n-1) and it seems right

Comment: but I don't understand why $2o(n-1)$ not $o(n-1)$

Comment: How do you reconcile the formula $o(n)=e(n)-n^{x-2}$ with $o(n)=e(n)-1$ in the case $x=3$?

Comment: @BarryCipra It should be $(x-2)^n$ rather than $n^{x-2}$, and can be proven by generalizing [Kevin P. Costello's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3041962).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way of seeing $o(n)=e(n)-1$ (which as you noted is enough to finish): Consider the following operation, which is defined on all sequences except the all $2$ sequence:

Take the first digit which is $0/1$, and switch it between $0$ and $1$.

For example, $2101$ is mapped to $2001$. Two things which you can quickly check about this map are

- Applying the map twice returns you to your original sequence.  So the map effectively pairs off the $3^n-1$ sequences that aren't all $2$.
- In each pair, one sequence has an even number of zeroes, the other has an odd number.

So those $3^n-1$ sequences are split evenly between even and odd.  The one left over sequence has no zeroes, so is even.

The same argument works if you have $x$ digits to choose from, the only difference being that there are now $(x-2)^n$ sequences containing neither $0$ nor $1$ that aren't paired off.

In combinatorics, this sort of argument is referred to as a sign-reversing involution.

Answer (score 3):

Given a string of length $n$, If the last digit is $0$ then you want to have even number of $0s$ in the first $n-1$ digits, hence $e(n-1)$. If the last digit is eigher $1$ or $2$, then you need an odd number of zeros in the first $n-1$ digits, hence $2o(n-1)$.

So we have $o(n)=2o(n-1)+e(n-1)=2o(n-1)+3^{n-1}-o(n-1)=3^{n-1}+o(n-1)$.

Multiplying both side by $x^n$ to get

$x^no(n)=x^n3^{n-1}+x^no(n-1)$ then

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^no(n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n3^{n-1}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^no(n-1)$

let $F(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^no(n)$, then

$F(x)-o(0)=x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n-1}3^{n-1}+x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n-1}o(n-1)$

$F(x)-o(0)=x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(3x)^{n-1}+xF(x)$

$F(x)(1-x)=x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(3x)^{n-1}$

$F(x)=\frac{x}{1-x}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(3x)^{n-1}$

$F(x)=\frac{x}{1-x}\frac{1}{1-3x}$

$F(x)=(\frac{-1}{2}+\frac{3^n}{2})\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$

so $o(n)=(\frac{3^n-1}{2})$

Comment: Generating functions seem excessive here. Once you have $o(n) = 3^{n-1} + o(n-1)$ and $o(1)=1$, you know $o(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 3^k = \frac{3^n-1}{3-1}$ by the formula for the sum of a geometric series. (And as a side note, bringing generating functions into a problem without a word of what you're doing is likely to confuse anyone, especially a reader that hasn't seen generating functions before. In general, writing up a solution to a math problem without using words is a terrible idea.)

Comment: Ah, that is right! I didn't thought that before, I went straight to generating fucntions haha

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $n$ is odd, $n = 2s+1$

Note that number of $n$-digit sequences with $k$ number of zeroes is ${N_k}(n) =$ $n \choose k$$2^{n-k}$.

Thus, $$o(n) = \sum_{m=0}^s{N_{2m+1}}(n) = \sum_{m=0}^s{n \choose 2m+1}{2^{n-2m-1}} = \sum_{m=0}^s{n \choose 2m+1}{1^{2m+1} 2^{n-2m-1}} \\ = \frac{(2+1)^n-(2-1)^n}{2} = \frac{3^n-1}{2}$$

If $n$ is even, let $n = 2t$. Then $o(n) = \sum_{m=0}^{t-1}{n \choose 2m+1}{2^{n-2m-1}} = \frac{3^n-1}{2}$, and you are done.

Moreover, $$o(n-1) = \frac{3^{n-1}-1}{2} \implies \fbox{$o(n-1) + 3^{n-1} = o(n)$}$$

Similarly, for $e(n)$, $$e(n)=\begin{cases}{\sum_{m=0}^s{n \choose 2m}{2^{n-2m}}}&n=2s+1 \\ \sum_{m=0}^t{n \choose 2m}{2^{n-2m}}& n = 2t\end{cases}$$

Thus, $$e(n) = \frac{(2+1)^n+(2-1)^n}{2} = \frac{3^n+1}{2}$$

Now, by further computation, one can find out that $\fbox{$e(n)-o(n) = 1$}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use exponential generating functions to solve this problem too.

Let $f(n)$ be the number of ternary sequences of length $n$ with an odd number of zeroes and let $F(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n)\frac{z^n}{n!}$ be the associated exponential generating function. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
\left(z+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}+\dotsb\right)\left(1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\dotsb\right)^2
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k_1+k_2+k_3=n\; k_1\, \text{odd}, k_2, k_3\geq 0}\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2! k_3!}\right)\frac{z^n}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n)\frac{z^n}{n!}
\end{align*}
$$
i.e. we have that
$$
F(z)=e^{2z}\times\frac{e^z-e^{-z}}{2}=\frac{e^{3z}-e^{z}}{2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{3^n-1}{2}\frac{z^n}{n!}
$$
whence
$$
f(n)=\frac{3^n-1}{2}\quad (n\geq 0).
$$